# full image asset not converting to base64 string

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactjs, base64, react-native

I'm using react-native to upload an image to a server. In order to do so, I need to get the image uri from the CameraRoll and convert it to a base64 string, which will subsequently be uploaded. Since its react-native a fair bit of this gets done in javascript, which I understand. However, the conversion from asset to base64 string occurs in objective-c, which I am not very fluent in, so I am relying on a bit of code from a different developer. Everything works fine, with the exception that the conversion of the image happens for a thumbnail of the original as opposed to the original itself. I want to convert the actual full image.

```
@interface ReadImageData : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
@end

@implementation ReadImageData

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(readImage:(NSString *)input callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{

  // Create NSURL from uri
  NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:input];

  // Create an ALAssetsLibrary instance. This provides access to the
  // videos and photos that are under the control of the Photos application.
  ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

  // Using the ALAssetsLibrary instance and our NSURL object open the image.
  [library assetForURL:url resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {

    // Create an ALAssetRepresentation object using our asset
    // and turn it into a bitmap using the CGImageRef opaque type.
    CGImageRef imageRef = [asset thumbnail];
    // Create UIImageJPEGRepresentation from CGImageRef
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef], 0.5);

    // Convert to base64 encoded string
    NSString *base64Encoded = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

    callback(@[base64Encoded]);

  } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"that didn't work %@", error);
  }];



}
@end
```

Clearly, the asset conversion happens with `[asset thumbnail]`. I looked up the docs and attempted to change it to `[asset originalAsset]`, which should return the full image, but instead I get an implicit conversion error. Namely:

*Implicit conversion of objective C pointer type 'ALAsset' to C pointer type 'CGImageRef' requires a bridge cast*

I tried to use a suggested solution, namely:

```
(__bridge CGImageRef)([asset originalAsset])
```

However, this causes my app to crash with this error:

*NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]*

So I am not sure how to proceed. The full article that has the referenced code is [here](https://medium.com/@scottdixon/react-native-creating-a-custom-module-to-upload-camera-roll-images-7a3c26bac309).

Answer (score 2):

In place of:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = [asset thumbnail];
```

Add these two lines:

```
ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
CGImageRef imageRef = [rep fullScreenImage];
```

Answer (score 1):

> I looked up the docs and attempted to change it to [asset originalAsset], which should return the full image

No, it shouldn't. You need to look more carefully at the docs. `originalAsset` is merely a pointer to another ALAsset, in case this asset has been edited. It is *not the image*. An ALAsset is not an image.

To access the image, pass through the asset's `defaultRepresentation`. This is an ALAssetRepresentation. Now you can get the full resolution CGImage.

Comment: Also, ALAsset is deprecated; you should be using the Photo Kit library at this point.

Comment: That's not an answer, its a comment.

Comment: There! Now I'm finished. Of course, all I'm doing is what you should have done - I read the docs. :)

Comment: This answer causes a build failure. When I try to couple it with the CGImage bridge it gives me the same error that I mentioned in my question.

Comment: The answer doesn't "cause" anything. It doesn't write your code for you. I just answer the question you asked - namely, why trying to treat the ALAsset's `originalAsset` crashes when you try to treat it as an image. It's because it isn't an image. And I showed you where the image lies. Thinking is up to you. (Of course, reading the docs was up to you too, and you didn't do that either.)